# Modular coin change program logic [Australian currency]

Tags: c

My aim with this program is to tell how many coins of each denomination should be given to a customer with the assumption of inputs being from 5-95.

I have written my program in the best modular form I can, and it seems to be working. However, the program shows 0 for each denomination.

What is the problem?

```
void PrintDisplay(void)
{   
    printf("Enter an amount to calculate change: ");
    return;
}

int GetChange(void)
{
    int change;
    scanf("%d%*c", &change);
    return(change);
}

int GetCoins(int cents, int coin)
{
    int quantity;
    quantity = cents / coin;
    return(quantity);
}

int GetNewChange(int cents, int coin)
{
    int newchange;
    newchange = cents - coin;
    return(newchange);
}

void PrintResult(int fifties, int twenties, int tens, int fives)
{
    printf("The amount of each coin denomination you should give are: \n");
    printf("Fifty cent coins: %d \n", fifties);
    printf("Twenty cent coins: %d \n", twenties);
    printf("Ten cent coins: %d \n", tens);
    printf("Five cent coins: %d \n", fives);
    return;
}

int main(int input)
{

    int FiftyCentAmount;
    int TwentyCentAmount;
    int TenCentAmount;
    int FiveCentAmount;
    PrintDisplay();
    GetChange();
    FiftyCentAmount = GetCoins(input, 50);
    GetNewChange(input, 50);
    TwentyCentAmount = GetCoins(input, 20);
    GetNewChange(input, 20);
    TenCentAmount = GetCoins(input, 10);
    GetNewChange(input, 10);
    FiveCentAmount = GetCoins(input, 5);
    GetNewChange(input, 5);
    PrintResult(FiftyCentAmount, TwentyCentAmount, TenCentAmount, FiveCentAmount);
    system("pause");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: you should not change your question according to the answer, this makes it impossible to understand the answer in the context of the question.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the answer.

Comment: you should edit your question back to its original state....

Comment: Are you supposed to ask a new question each time 1 out of some errors are fixed?

Comment: Not really, you can highlight that there are more problems then just the one discovered in the comments, but changing the content of the question makes the answers given look strange. Basically your question is completly answered by Dave. See my coming answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetChange() returns the user's input, but you aren't saving the result of the call.  You want

```
input = GetChange();
```

Comment: So after that I wouldn't need any parameters in main?

Comment: The arguments to main() are always argc (the number of command line arguments) and argv (an array of pointers to the command line arguments).  See (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html).  So if you don't care about command line arguments, you wouldn't need to specify any arguments to main().

Comment: @wil At this point if you have a debugger you should just step thru the code and look at the values of your variables.  Or if no debugger, put in some printf() statements to print the value, e.g. have GetCoins() print the cents, the coin, and the return quantity.

Answer (score 4):

A function has an input (the parameters), an output (return value and maybe parameters passed by pointer) and an algorithm that generates the output from the input.

Sometimes function do not really have an input or output like your superflous `PrintDisplay`. This is generally okay if you make your code more readable/ better organized that way. Your function is superflous because you make a function (which has four lines) for a simple one line statement. Not inherently bad but superflous.

The return value "appears" at the position where the function call was made. So if you do

```
input = GetChange();
```

`input` will be set to the return value of `GetChange`.

You fixed this after Daves answer, but didn't see that all your `Get...` functions also have a return value you just ignore in your code.

So by fixing all of them your code should work (or not see edit).

All your functions (except `PrintResult` and the textinput) are basically oneliners. And

They reduce to

```
int GetCoins(int cents, int coin)
{
    return cents / coin;
}

int GetNewChange(int cents, int coin)
{
    return cents - coin;
}
```

So an improved program (in your design) would look like this then:

```
int main()
{
    int leftover_change;

    printf("Enter an amount to calculate change: ");

    leftover_change= GetChange();

    int FiftyCentAmount = GetCoins(leftover_change, 50);
    leftover_change = GetNewChange(leftover_change, 50);

    int TwentyCentAmount = GetCoins(leftover_change, 20);
    leftover_change = GetNewChange(leftover_change, 20);

    int TenCentAmount = GetCoins(leftover_change, 10);
    leftover_change = GetNewChange(leftover_change, 10);

    int FiveCentAmount = GetCoins(leftover_change, 5);
    leftover_change = GetNewChange(leftover_change, 5);

    PrintResult(FiftyCentAmount, TwentyCentAmount, TenCentAmount, FiveCentAmount);

    if(leftover_change >0)
    {
        printf("there are %d cents left\n", leftover_change);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

This still vioaltes the DRY concept (Dont repeat yourself) you could fix this (at least partially) by replacing the magic numbers with defines or const variables.

Even better would be a loop that iterates through the different coins. But this needs a bit more thinking and the use of arrays.

edit: I did not check the algorithm in the first place, and my `scanf`reduction was bullshit but I was in a hurry so here a version that works. To make this answer complete, but as Dave said you should check your algorithm before you implement it.

```
int GetNewChange(int cents, int coin)
{
    return cents % coin; //this is the modulus operator
}
```

Comment: As stated in the original question, I tried to make the code as modular as possible. I didn't want to go into detail about why it was modular so I can understand your use and answer regarding the functions being superfluous. After Daves answer I got my code working, however I received weird outputs in negatives which was worked out to be because of the re-use of input. So by adding some if(cents >= coin) statements I was able to rinse some of those negative numbers and the program works much better. All factors of 5 from 10 up print out fine, but 90 and past there are some issues, why is that?

Comment: @Wil two things I'd suggest.  First, forget about the computer and C and functions, and just go thru the steps of making changing, writing what you are doing on a piece of paper, and not omitting or assuming anything.  Then, "hand-execute" your code, again with a piece of paper, writing down the values of variables.  Or run it thru a debugger if you have access to one, and just go line by line, looking at values.  I think you'll find that your code doesn't quite reflect the algorithm that you yourself would use.

Comment: @Wil it's better that you ask a new question, than to ask people to answer more questions in the comments.

Comment: @YvetteColomb In regard to the edit: It may have been obvious to you, but people who do not understand it do not neccessarily know that they don't. Still the edit is okay, as it was a personal message.