# C Wont cycle through functions

Tags: c

My program will not progress once I assign a value to `input`, it does not freeze or crash, it simply won't progress to `changecalc()`.

Have I correctly coded my function main?

```
int getinput(void)
{
    int input;
    printf("enter a value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    return(input);
}
void changecalc(int co)
{
    int var1=0;
    int ver2=0;
    int var3=0;
    int var4=0;

    while(co > 0);{
        if (co >= 50){
            var1++; 
            co = co -50;
        }
        else if (co >= 20){
            var2++; 
            co = co - 20;
        }
        else if (co >= 10){
            var3++; 
            co = co - 10;
        }
        else if (co >= 5){
            var4++; 
            co = co - 5;
        }
        else if (co <= 0){
            printf("var1:%d, var2:%d, var3:%d, var4:%d", var1, var2, var3, var4);
        }
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int changeowed;
    void changecalc(int changeowed);
    changeowed = getinput();
    changecalc(changeowed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should step through your code in debugger. It would show you the problem with `while(co > 0);{`.

Comment: @user694733: Arguably though does appear to crash a line by line debugger, so I have some sympathy, plus the code is well-written.

Comment: Mhhhh I've seen this task [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372685/modular-coin-change-program-logic-australian-currency)

Comment: this can be done much simpler with modulo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
while(co > 0);{
             ^
             ups - while(co > 0); is an endless loop
```

to

```
while(co > 0){
```

Besides that you have another problem with the loop. Consider your code (without the ;):

```
            while(co > 0){
                if (co >= 50){
                    var1++; //increases var1 by one
                    co = co -50;
                }
                else if (co >= 20){
                    var2++; //increases var2 by one
                    co = co - 20;
                }
                else if (co >= 10){
                    var3++; //var3 by one
                    co = co - 10;
                }
                else if (co >= 5){
                    var4++; //var4 by one
                    co = co - 5;
                }
                else if (co <= 0){
                    printf("var1:%d, var2:%d, var3:%d, var4:%d", var1, var2, var3, var4);
                }
            }
            return;
```

What will happen if `co`is equal to 1?

You'll have **another endless loop** as `co` wont be changed further.

Maybe you should change the whole thing to:

```
            while(1){
                if (co >= 50){
                    var1++; //increases var1 by one
                    co = co -50;
                }
                else if (co >= 20){
                    var2++; //increases var2 by one
                    co = co - 20;
                }
                else if (co >= 10){
                    var3++; //increases var3 by one
                    co = co - 10;
                }
                else if (co >= 5){
                    var4++; //increases var4 by one
                    co = co - 5;
                }
                else {
                    printf("var1:%d, var2:%d, var3:%d, var4:%d", var1, var2, var3, var4);

                    break; // end the loop
                }
            }
```

**A few other observations:**

In `main` you have the line `void changecalc(int changeowed);` Don't do that. Simply delete the line. It doesn't do anything and it can safely be deleted.

In `getinput` you do `scanf("%d", &input);` Don't do like that. Always check the value returned by `scanf` (which is the number of variables successfully populated). Like:

```
if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
{
    // Put error handling here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Regarding the changecalc function, why should I not call it in main? as for the error handling my next step was to ensure that the value for getinput was divisible by 5.

Comment: @tanksux I'm not saying that you shall not call `changecalc` in `main`. The line I tell you to delete, i.e. `void changecalc(int changeowed);`is **not** a call of the function. It's rather an unnecessary forward declaration so just delete it. The call of the function happens in this line `changecalc(changeowed);`

Comment: @4386427 thanks for your insight, I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

This one is particularly vexing as it will appear to crash a line by line debugger.

`while(co > 0);` is an *empty* `while` loop, and will run forever!

Remove the `;`.

Note also that you'll loop indefinitely for another reason if `co` is ever 1, 2, 3, or 4; it's often a good idea to finish a long `if` `else` block with an 
 `else` so you cover all possibilities explicitly.